# Doesn't call OnModelCreating after Restart

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis

I have a project with EntityFramework as an OR Mapper. I have  a class which overwrites `DbContext` and the method "OnModelCreating" where I initialize the mapping of my EntityFramework.

If I build the solution and start it with IIS Express, everything works fine and "OnModelCreating" is called. If I stop the application and start it again(no rebuild), "OnModelCreating" isn't called and I get an Exception. The same if I deploy my project to the local IIS. I deploy the project, start it and everything works fine. If I reset my IIS, I will get the same Exception.

The Exception is

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'x' and 'y'. The principal end of this association must be
>   explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data
>   annotations.

I don't know since when we have this error and where the bug is. I thought `OnModelCreating` should be called once if I start the application, but it looks like there is still something in the cache. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? Everyone in the team has the same error. I can post different code snippets if needed. If someone want the see our OR Mapper: We use **NopCommerce 3.80**. You can download the sourcecode on their page.